# MATLAB struct conversion error

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

I have 5 different structure and I want to calculate some variables for all of them. To do that, I wrote the following code:

```
for i=1:5
[StructureI(i), ReqTab(i), jt(i), B(i)]=Checkall(E);
end
```

The values `StructureI, ReqTab, jt and B` are calculated in another function and they are

```
StructureI= 1X4 matrix,
ReqTab= 4X2 matrix,
jt=2x1 matrix,
B=4x4 matrix
```

When I run the code it calculates all the varibles in the function Checkall. However, when it turns to the parent code, it gives and error "Conversion to double from struct is not possible."

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The structures that you mention contain just one matrix each. Why are you using structures at all then? Couldn't you just return `StructureI` as a 2D matrix and then use a third dimension to store the dirrefernt results in each loop? (same for the other 3 vars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign directly from double to struct, instead you have to write the specific field `field_name` to assign to:

```
[StructureI(i).field_name, ReqTab(i), jt(i), B(i)] = Checkall(E);
```

If all of these variables (i.e. also `ReqTab`, `jt`, `B`) are structures, then off course you need to specify the field in each one of them, using the `.` notation.

However, as mentioned in the comments, all iterations of your loop are just the same (no usage of `i` within it), so why do you need this loop? just to make 5 copies?